# Annotation and methods

Tags: java, annotations

Is there a way to call a method method in annotation

For example

```
@Annotation(param = Class.method();)
```

or is there anoter way?

Comment: Do you want the parameter to refer to the method, or to actually be the result of invoking the method?

Comment: Sort answer, no. Parameters must be compile time constants. Annotations are part of the code - often used by compile time annotation processors.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman
I want to get the result of the method.

Comment: Then what @BoristheSpider said: it's not really going to work.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible by providing the name of the function into the annotation

Heres a class I wrote which contains the generic function 'callMethod()' which takes in a String and instance of a class and returns the result of calling that method.

```
public static <T> Object callMethod(String methodName, T classInstance) throws NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
    Method method = classInstance.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(methodName);
    return method.invoke(classInstance);
}
```